# Vue + Axios with sessionStorage

Tags: vue.js, axios, session-storage

**Goal:** Initially load posts using the Wordpress Rest API via Axios once in a Vue View, and only once during a session of visiting the Vue website.

**Current Result:** I currently fetch the results successfully and set them in sessionStorage. They display correctly. I want to know/learn if I am accomplishing this correctly and have the process optimized in the best way possible. I've looked up documentation and I think I have it down.

**Current Code:**

```
<script>
import Hero from "@/components/Hero.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "About",
  components: {
    Hero,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      eatery: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("//localhost:81/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=5&categories=2")
      .then((response) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("eatery", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error);
      });
  },
  mounted() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("eatery")) {
      this.eatery = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("eatery"));
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Looking good Would be even better to check if there isNot `"eatery"` in `sessionStorage` before calling `axios.get`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me learn more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check whether it's in the storage before trying to load it. In your case, it would look like this:

```
export default {
  name: "About",
  components: {
    Hero,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      eatery: [],
    };
  },
  loadEatery() {
    axios
      .get("//localhost:81/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=5&categories=2")
      .then((response) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("eatery", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error); // for debugging maybe
      });
  },
  mounted() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("eatery")) {
      this.eatery = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("eatery"));
    } else {
      loadEatery().then(data => this.eatery = data);
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the visualization! I appreciate it.

Comment: I've actually run into a small issue with the function loadEatery. If the data doesn't exist, it attempts to fetch the data using `loadEatery().then(data => this.eatery = data);`. This works, however, I'm getting the error `TypeError: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference` and `Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference`. I'm unsure how to fix that line of code.